# $x^x$ graph - what does it look like?

Tags: graphing-functions, exponentiation

Out of curiosity, what does the $x^x$ graph look like?

I physically cannot picture it when $x < 0$. Does such a thing exist or do we only define the domain to be $x > 0$ where it's just a usual steep exponential?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not really useful to define $x^y$ when $x<0$ and $y$ is not an integer. So the function $x^x$ really shouldn't be defined when $x<0$. If you allow complex values, then you still ought to be dealing with a multi-valued function.

Comment: Try inputting "x^x" into WolframAlpha.

Comment: @FrankVel Everytime I input it, it only shows for $x > 0$

Comment: @TripleA I realized it would only work for positive integers on Google, but WolframAlpha should still give you a graph for negative values.

Comment: [Here](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/gallery/rogue/xx_exponential.html) is GrafEq's take on it.

Answer (score 7):

The function $f(x)=x^x$ usually isn't defined for $x<0$.  Notice, for example, that

$$f(-1/2)=(-1/2)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{-2}$$

and square roots of negative numbers generally isn't a good thing when you are graphing.

Just for your curiosity, the graph may be found [on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eyrp4fln9m) and for convenience, it is also below:

[image]

For $x<0$, one may, if persistent, have complex numbers, and the graph is given by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex).  Below is a snippet:

[image]

For more interesting graphs, you could modify the input, like [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%20for%20-10%3Cx%3C0).

---

WolframAlpha may even draw some [3D graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%20for%20-10%2Bi%3Cx%3Ci,%20-2%3Cy%3C2) as you asked for:

[image]

Comment: Apparently it's a 3D diagram for $ x < 0$, which is fascinating yet confusing

Comment: @TripleA 3D?  Are you intending to have $x$ be complex numbers?  As I'd rather not...

Comment: I know it isn't conventional but it bugs me too much for me not to know

Comment: @TripleA Note that, according to Wolfram Alpha, $(-1)^{1/3}$ is $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$, rather than $-1$.

Comment: @TripleA Learn Euler's formula and try to put $y=x^x$ into the form $y=re^{i\theta}$ and you might get an intuitive graph.

Comment: @TripleA Could try checking my last sentence.  May help.

Comment: That plot by wolfram alpha gives the impression that $x^x$ is a continuous complex-valued function for $x < 0$. But is that the case? Isn't $\Im(x^x) = 0$ whenever $x$ is rational with odd denominator, and nonzero elsewhere? Isn't it dense with discontinuities? Is there some way to choose branches everywhere so that the whole function conspires to be continuous?

Comment: @ziggurism It's assuming some principal branch, which can indeed give a continuous complex-valued function. As noted by the graph, this does not give real values when $x$ is rational with odd denominator though.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt right I get it now. For the principal branch of logarithm, $\exp(x \log x)$ is a continuous function. But it does not agree with the “principal” value of $x^x$ for rational $x$, except I think at integer values. The latter function is highly discontinuous, composed of different selections of branches of logarithm, densely interspersed.

Comment: @ziggurism Depends on what is meant by "principal value of $x^x$".

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think I meant rational, not real. (And I edited to say so). For rational $x=p/q$, let’s call the principal $p/q$th power the positive one when $q$ is even, and the real one when $q$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

In real analysis, 
$$
x^x:=e^{x\ln x},\quad x>0. 
$$
by definition. And goolge tells you it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hahaha, Google?  For graphing?  Wow, I didn't even know this...

Comment: If one searches `x^x` in Google, then the graph would come out.

Comment: Wow, that's easy.  Is it for general graphs?  Or... hm...

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a usual steep exponential; it has a little dip at the beginning. We don't usually define it for $x < 0$, or at least not for all $x$; $x^x$ is only real for $x < 0$ if $x$ is an integer or a fraction with odd denominator.

For graphing, I recommend WolframAlpha (www.wolframalpha.com). Just type "graph x^x" in the window. You'll notice that WolframAlpha *does* define it for negative values, but the result is a complex number.

Comment: But I want to know what it looks like for $x < 0$

Comment: @TripleA I don't know what you're typing into WolframAlpha - it shows $x < 0$ for me. Try typing "graph x^x for x < 0".

Comment: @TripleA: It's not usually defined there unless you use complex numbers. Wolfram Alpha shows what it looks like if you use complex numbers. But there's ambiguity because the log of a complex number is not a well-defined function. Wolfram Alpha just uses the most common (I believe) convention for choosing a log of complex numbers.